# Kafka and the concept of needing a foreign key from previous record for next records to insert

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka

After much searching I could not get an answer on hom to implement one of the most basic db inserts.
(The fact that I could not get an answer even addressing this concept makes me think that I am just not thinking in the `kafka-way`)

> - A much used example would be where a customer places an order and the    order contains many products.
> - When the order is inserted, the traditional method would be to insert the order with all the data that it may contain (userID,
>     payment, discount etc..), send back the primary_key, insert this key
>     as a foreign field on all the products, and then insert all the
>     products.
> - This of coarse would later have the effect of just querying the order, and    then with the foreign key getting all the products that belong
>     to    that order.

So I am wondering how this would be implemented in Kafka?

This is what I was thinking:

> - I would produce an order from the front end with Rest Api into a    kafka `initial-orders` topic. This topic would then write it to my ordersDB.
> - The db would then write back into kafka as a producer the order with    its primary_key into a kafka `final-orders` topic.
> - After inserting the order, my frontend would make repeated    fetchRequests (maybe using KSQL) to the kafka `final-orders` topic for an order that contains all the same values as the order that it just inserted.
> - When it gets a return, it just inserts the primary_id field into the products and sends it to the kafka `products` topic who then writes it into the products db.

My problem with this approach is:

- What happens when my front-end does not receive data back form the
  repeated fetchRequests. Do I timeout after lets say a second and try and reverse everything? What if
  the network is slow? Should I rather send all the data (order and products) to kafka at
  once and let kafka sort it out internally and only send back a
  `200_OK` if everything went well?

Comment: This isn't particularly a Kafka problem, rather reactive microservices and distributed transactions. You might want to look at the architecture pattern of "distributed sagas"

Comment: Thanks, I did not really know that the answer or the question was... :)

Comment: The issue is guaranteeing ordering and consistency. For example, expand orders and products to include shipping, then you've included a third service that needs to notify the others that the product of the order was delivered. Basically, though, Kafka isn't going to "sort things out" on its own. If the network is slow, then that should be a server side issue (your front end wouldn't be consuming directly from Kafka, rather reflecting state of the server side consumer} but polling or websockets is one way to get updates shown back to a user, similar to how you'd implement a notification system

Comment: Thanks, that have already cleared up a lot for me - especially the "your front end wouldn't be consuming directly from Kafka" line. I basically know all the individual technologies, I just have to figure out there working order for a standard app...

Comment: Maybe this helps https://blog.sebastian-daschner.com/entries/event_sourcing_cqrs_video_course